# How do we know Karna was a great Danavira?

Tags: karna

Karna is considered as one of the greatest danaviras. However, the greatest form of dana is the one that is given secretly. If such is the case, then ideally Karna's dana should have remained secret forever but still we all know he was the greatest danavira. How is this not a contradiction?